# react native: reduce all data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

now i learning react native, can someone explain me? how to sum json data to text.
example i have crypto json data in SAMPLE_DATA and i want to sum the current_price.

i read in documentation, its using reduce, but i don't understand how to apply

```
const reducer = (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue;

const HomeScreen = () => {
return(
<Text data={SAMPLE_DATA}>{current_price.reduce(reducer)</Text>
)
}
```

but it's error, i don't understand

Comment: First of all, fix the typo and see if this works: the parenthesis aren't balanced. If it still does not work, please show where `current_price` is defined and set.

Comment: Hey @dickareynaldi, I’m having trouble understanding your question. . I think you’re asking how to turn JSON data into a string. Please write what you're trying to accomplish, the problem and what have you tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.